# How to add two numbers in jinja

Tags: django, jinja2

I have a mark object which I want to list in table

```
{% for mark in marks %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                    <td>{{mark.subject.name}}</td>
                    <td>75</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                    <td>{{mark.mark}}</td>
                    <td>{{mark.mark_pr}}</td>
                    <td>{{ (mark.mark + mark.mark_pr) }}</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>70</td>
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to display the sum of mark.mark and mark.mark_pr into third last  but when I try doing
(mark.mark + mark.mark_pr) it gives me error saying "Could not parse the remainder: '(mark.mark + mark.mark_pr)' from '(mark.mark + mark.mark_pr)" do anyone have any idea on how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution is to conduct the addition on the backend, then pass the sum as an attribute of a `mark` to the template.

Comment: What is `marks`? If I try to reproduce this problem with [some simple Python code](https://gist.github.com/larsks/e25636a386a8c4de57151b5e8e97732b) it all works as expected (except that `forloop.counter` is spelled `loop.counter`).

Comment: Mark is the queryset i am filtering it like this marks = Mark.objects.filter(student=std,exam=exam,grade=grade) and mark.mark,mark.mark_pr are integer field in the model